# How to set the Reconstruction error threshold for anomaly detection using autoencoders?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, unsupervised-learning, autoencoder

Hi I am doing anomaly detection using auto encoders.I have trained the model using 'Non Anomalous' values.Now when I give anomalous points as test data.

What should be the **Reconstruction error** threshold I should give to classify it as whether it is anomalous or not?

I have currently set it to 0.1 , but it doesnt find any anomalies(actually test data have lot of anomalies)
What are the factors that I should consider before setting the value?

Comment: Have you tried using Z-score? You can check this link: https://lavastorm.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009526673-Outlier-Detection-Using-Modifed-Z-Score

Answer (score 0):

If one considers prediction of anomalous status as binary classification (i.e., if reconstruction error < threshold, classify as normal, else classify as anomalous), one can find the threshold that maximizes some appropriate metric of classification performance (e.g., F-beta) by optimizing the metric over a suitable validation set containing normal and anomalous data. See [Malhotra et al., 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00148) for an example of how to do this for time series.